# Phonegap installation failure. Sticking to version 0.9.4 by default

Tags: node.js, cordova

Ive been trying to install phonegap for hours now. For some reason by default it installs version 0.9.4 (when I do npm install -g phonegap). If I specify to use latest version (npm install -g phonegap@5.0.0-0.28.1) I get tonns of errors for almost every dependency out there. Tried reinstalling node, removing modules, clearing npm cache, etc.

Windows 7
Node version 0.12.5 (x64)
Npm version 2.11.2

Comment: Please post some of the errors that occur and for which dependencies - I'm personally a Mac person so I don't have the foggiest idea about what's wrong, but I'm sure someone else will eventually help

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem before with my Mac
to fix this, i just simply ran

```
npm update -g phonegap
```

and behold it updated itself to 5.0.0

Comment: I exactly the same issue on my Mac (10.9.5) on a clean install of node (0.12.5) & npm (2.12.0). Running an update as above fixed the issue. I hope this helps out on Windows too...